# How to show a row in excel if there is a X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

i am busy learning excel but i need to show the passed students with a formula. everyone with a "X" at "exam passed" need to show up under "who passed?" with all the grades and names. all the students without a "X" behind their name don't need to show up under "Who Passed?"

I tried a if statement but i am not getting the results i want

Comment: "with all the grades and names" In one cell? In one column? Separate columns? You should show exact desired result and formula you tried.

Comment: If you have Office 365: FILTER(): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: i want all the grades and names of everyone who passed in different columns. i tried =IF($G2="X". but after that i dont know how to go further

Comment: `=FILTER($B$2:$E$7,$G$2:$G$7="x")` for different columns, or `=BYROW(FILTER($A$2:$E$7,$G$2:$G$7="x"),LAMBDA(Student,TRIM(TEXTJOIN(" " & $B$1:$E$1 & ": ",FALSE,Student))))` in a single cell, on different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FILTER Function: "filters" a range of data based on supplied criteria(X). The result is an array(B2:E7) of matching values(X) from the original range(G2:G7).

```
=FILTER(B2:E7,G2:G7="X")
```

[image]

Comment: if i do this i get the error message this function is invalid

Comment: I have assumed you are in ms365, i dont know your excel version

Comment: If you are getting invalid, it could also mean that you need to use something beside `,` for the delimiter like `;` @MikeOa

Comment: Yes thank you i needed to use a ; instead of a ,